# Count how many rows satisfy a certain filter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, pandas-groupby

I am working with 2 different dataframes (general and last) which are something like this:

```
general=pandas.DataFrame(columns=["code","grade","year","quarter","subject"],data=[[01,4.5,2011,1,1],[01,5.0,2012,2,1],[23,5.0,2013,1,2],[01,7.5,2011,1,2])
last=pandas.DataFrame(columns=["code","grade","subject"],data=[[01,5.0,1],[01,7.5,2],[23,5.0,2])
```

I want to add in "last" a column named "attempts" in which I get the number of attempts that a student has taken to pass the subject.(Basically, add a column with the number of rows that satisfy certain criteria).
I have tried using this:

```
last["ATTEMPTS"]=None
for ind in general.index:
    st=general.loc[ind]["code"]
    subject=general.loc[ind]["subject"]
    fil1=grades["code"]==st
    fil2=grades["subject"]==subject
    attempts=len(general[fil1&fil2])
    last.at[ind, "ATTEMPTS"] = attempts
```

But it takes too long... Any easier ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @jpp, I have updated my question! Hope you can understand now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `groupby.size()`, then align indices to map your results.

For performance, you should avoid iterating rows in a `pandas` dataframe in favour of vectorised computations.

**Setup**

I have changed data slightly to make it more interesting example, and fixed syntax errors.

```
general = pd.DataFrame(columns=["code","grade","year","quarter","subject"],data=[[1,4.5,2011,1,1],[1,5.0,2012,2,1],[23,5.0,2013,1,2],[1,7.5,2011,1,2]])
last = pd.DataFrame(columns=["code","grade","subject"],data=[[1,5.0,1],[1,7.5,2],[23,5.0,2], [1, 6.0, 1]])
```

**Solution**

```
s = last.groupby(['code', 'subject']).size()
general['ATTEMPTS'] = general.set_index(['code', 'subject']).index.map(s.get)
```

**Result**

```
print(general)

   code  grade  year  quarter  subject  ATTEMPTS
0     1    4.5  2011        1        1         2
1     1    5.0  2012        2        1         2
2    23    5.0  2013        1        2         1
3     1    7.5  2011        1        2         1
```